# Suppose $V$ is a vector space over field $F$, $\operatorname{char}(F)\neq 2$. Show that $V=V^+ \oplus V^-$, details below

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $T$ be a linear transformation $T: V\rightarrow V, T^2=I$. Define $$V^+ =\{v\in V \mid T(V)= +v \}, V^-=\{ v\in V \mid T(v)= -v \}.$$

My understanding of fields is still weak, does $\operatorname{char}(F)\neq 2$ just mean we are not dealing with the finite field with two elements? Can someone provide an example of when what I am trying to show is true?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra)

Comment: It means your field does not contain as a subfield the field with two elements.

Answer (score 0):

use $v=\frac{v+T(v)}{2}+\frac{v-T(v)}{2}$ since $T(\frac{v+T(v)}{2})=\frac{v+T(v)}{2}$ and $T(\frac{v-T(v)}{2})=(\frac{T(v)-T(T(v))}{2})=\frac{T(v)-v}{2}=\color{red}- \frac{v-T(v)}{2}$

And if  $v_0\in V^+ \cap V^-$ we have $T(v_0)=v_0=-v_0$ it means $2v_0=0$ contradict with  $F, char(F)\neq 2$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will think about it some more.

Comment: welcome dear. only as I mensioned in answer about last part, i amnot sure.

Comment: For a field $F$ of characteristic 2 consider $T\colon F^2\rightarrow F^2$ defined by the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ (with respect to the standard basis). Then $T^2 = {\rm id}$ (because of $1+1=0$ in $F$), but $F^2$ does not allow a decomposition into eigenspaces.

Comment: @user218931 How can I get contradict for last part?

Comment: @RaziehNoori What do you mean? For $T$ as defined above we have $T^2 = {\rm id}$ although $V\neq V^+\oplus V^-$. Because of ${\rm char}(F) = 2$ we have $V^+ = V^-$; and if $V= V^+\oplus V^-$ were true, then actually $V = V^+$, but this implies $T = {\rm id}$, a contradiction.

Comment: in question he has mentiond ${char}(F)\neq 2$. then i want conclude $2v_0=0$, where $v_0\in V^+\cap V^-$

Comment: if ${\rm char}(F)\neq 2$, then $2v_0 = 0$ already implies $v_0 = 0$ (because $2$ is invertible in $F$ and hence $v_0 = 1\cdot v_0 =(2^{-1}\cdot 2)\cdot v_0 = 2^{-1}\cdot (2v_0) = 2^{-1}\cdot 0 = 0$).